# Enum values are not imported when adding WCF Service Reference

Tags: c#, wcf, enums

I have created a WCF that has a enum

```
enum LogType {
   Warning = 1,
   Error,
   Fatal
}
```

When add reference for above created Service using the service metadata, The Service Reference code generated contains

```
enum LogType {
   Warning,
   Error,
   Fatal
}
```

It does not contain that 1 value, thus the values are mismatching after <s>transmission</s> (Check Edit 1).

Can I add any attributes so that enum values are also created..

## Edit 1:

Sorry it is not transmission.

Before sending enum value as Error, I am performing a typecast from integer(1 -> Warning). This typecast will be incorrect, since 1 will be typecasted to Error.

Comment: What network protocol are you using? SOAP?

Comment: Try using `DataContractAttribute` on enum and `EnumMemberAttribute` on the values explicitly

Comment: _"the values are mismatching after transmission"_ - why? [Enums are mapped on name, not on value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry @CodeCaster, usr Check  #Edit1

Comment: Your edit has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[DataContract]` attribute to the `Enum` and `[EnumMember]` to each value.

Comment: Have you tried without putting values to enum. Any business requirement to have the value. By Default it should work